# Can't connect to local server with android emulator

Tags: java, android, networking

I am trying to develop a simple android login and registration application which will fetch data from local server(for now). I am using android studio and WAMP server. I have provided the internet permission in the manifest file. I have tried the urls:

- 10.0.2.2
- 127.0.0.1
- 192.168.1.5(my IPv4 address)
- 192.168.1.5:8080
- localhost:80

Still evry time it shows

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.1.5:8080 (or any of the above) refused
```

I have been trying this and followed every advice but the application stops unfortunately(as the emulator says).I have posted all my required java files and logcat in my previous question here: [Unfortunately the application stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23646793/unfortunately-the-application-stopped-working/23647284?noredirect=1#comment36320974_23647284).
It would be of great help if anyone guides me on this.

Comment: This may be a stupid question but the IP listed is the address of the WAMP server, and the android device is connected to the same WiFi network as the WAMP server, correct? Can you access the page from any other device on the network? Can you load it from the web-browser? It may be an issue with routing and your server configuration, not necessarily the app.

Comment: try 10.0.2.2 with the port number.. @user3467651

Comment: Try accessing that like `http://10.0.2.2:8080`

Comment: @MattClark Yes the android emulator is working on the same WiFi network as the WAMP server. When I tried localhost/webservices/login/register.php or 127.0.0.1/webservices/login.php or localhost:80/webservices/login.php in the mozilla firefox it opens but with others it doesn't load.One more thing,this may sound the stupidest but as with no experience with WAMP, do I have to put it online before using. Although I have tried it with no results.

Comment: I have done that @Lal but it shows problem loading page in the browser.

Comment: Is the emulator running on the same machine as the server or on a different machine?

Comment: Yes they are running on the same device.I the httpd.conf file it shows servername as localhost:80

Comment: Did you try `http://10.0.2.2:80` ???

Comment: Check your firewalls..Best is that you disable them completely while testing..

Answer (score 0):

Use `10.0.2.2:8080` to connect to local server if server is running at port number `8080`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, until I got here
FYI: I had to change port on Wampserver (from port 80 to port 8080, because port 80 was already used (cmd, netstat -aon). 
In my java class, I tried above addresses, but only 10.0.2.2:8080 helped for me.